# How do I automate testing for hybrid apps which has it's web view resources from assets?

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, android-webview, hybrid, appium-android

I am using Appium for testing my Android Hybrid App.

What parameter should I give for the `RemoteWebDriver` constructor? I tried giving the html file path from the internal storage, but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

> ```
> package firsttestngpackage;
> import java.net.MalformedURLException;
> import java.net.URL;
> ```

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FirstTestNGFile {

    WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException{
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities(); 
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");    
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1"); 
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "MotoG5splus");    
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");  
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium"); 
capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\chandrahas\\Downloads");  
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(""),capabilities);

capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.reliance.agencydev");
}   
    @Test
  public void testirm()throws Exception {
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"userName\"]/input")).sendKeys("9642039085");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]/input")).sendKeys("password");;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Appium server running? If it's on your local machine, try with:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"), capabilities);
```

Also try moving the line where you declare appPackage capability to before you create your driver.